# Is "velocity of money" explicitly/literally defined in Calculus terms? (Or is the word just being used colloquially for "movement")

Tags: calculus

Is "velocity of money" explicitly/literally defined in Calculus terms?
$$v(t) = s'(t)$$

(Or is the word velocity merely being used colloquially to connote "movement")

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity_of_money

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a quotient: a financial aggregate representing the value of transactions in a given time period divided by a financial aggregate representing the amount of the money available.  Economists have particular problems defining the money supply.

So the *velocity of money* is an average over a time period and has dimension $T^{-1}$.

As far as I am aware, it is not the derivative of anything and, even if the concept of the instantaneous velocity of money was theoretically possible by taking arbitrarily shorter time intervals, its integral would simply be the average using a different unit of time.

This suggests *velocity of money* is an example of a scientific and mathematical concept abused by economists.

So *speed of money use* might be slightly better as there is no direction, and *frequency of money use* could be even closer to the concept as there is no distance.

Comment: I would not go so far as to say "velocity of money" is a concept that is being abused, because it is not clear that the economic meaning was adopted from the physical meaning beyond loose inspiration.

Comment: You speak of taking arbitrarily short time intervals, but what about arbitrarily large populations?

Comment: Ok, so it's not a literal derivative, but just a word that connotes "action" or "turnover"or "movement"   Thanks!